# Geometric distribution Abel's partial summation expectation

Tags: summation, expected-value

It is $0 < q \le 1$ and P=Geom(q) the geometric distribution on $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$ and $X(\omega)=\omega$.
Determine EX and Var(X) with  Abel's partial summation:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_n +\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\sum_{j=1}^{k}a_j)(b_k-b_{k+1})$
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},a_j,b_j \in \mathbb{R},j \in \{1,...,n\}$.

Consider the special case $q=1$ and don't take the limit $n \to \infty$ at the start.

Comment: The formula you provided for the partial summation has a serious flaw; please double check it and make corrections.  In particular, you have one sum over $j$ but no expression is indexed by this variable.  I assume you meant $\sum_{j=1}^k a_j$.

Comment: This is the formulation of the exercise sheet.. I see know that this is wrong

Comment: Because i have to start the problem again, solutions are welcome.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, please feel free to provide your revised computation.  You are also welcome to try the variance computation, for which I have provided a hint in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perhaps more convenient to first let $p = 1-q$.  Then if we use your choices $a_k = (1-q)^{k-1} = p^{k-1}$, $b_k = k$, the formula
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k = b_n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^k a_j (b_k - b_{k+1}) \tag{1}$$ becomes
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n k p^{k-1} 
&= n \sum_{k=1}^n p^{k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^k p^{j-1} \\
&= n \frac{1 - p^n}{1-p} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1 - p^k}{1-p} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-p} \left( n(1-p^n) - (n-1) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} p^k \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{1-p} \left(1 - np^n + \frac{p-p^n}{1-p} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{(1-p)^2} ( 1 - np^n - p + np^{n+1} + p - p^n ) \\
&= \frac{1 - (n+1)p^n + np^{n+1}}{(1-p)^2}.
\end{align}$$
Then as $n \to \infty$, for $0 < p < 1$, the numerator tends to $1$ and the expectation is $$\operatorname{E}[X] = q \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k = \frac{q}{(1-p)^2} = \frac{1}{q}.$$

To perform the variance calculation using the same method, it is natural to choose $b_k = k^2$, but I would recommend choosing $b_k = k(k-1)$ instead.  This will give $\operatorname{E}[X(X-1)] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]$, from which we can still recover the variance.

Comment: thanks for the quick in-depth answer. Now i don't have to start again from the beginning.

Comment: @GE94 If you found the answer helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: I can't upvote  at the moment with my reputation, but now i know the accepting and upvoting